# Javascript snowing function?

Tags: javascript

This is the function im doing, the only thing I want to change is have the snow appear BEHIND everything; so its not on top of divs and whatnot; I just want it to appear in the background of everything. Here is the code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set the number of snowflakes (more than 30 - 40 not recommended)
    var snowmax=35

    // Set the colors for the snow. Add as many colors as you like
    var snowcolor=new Array("#aaaacc","#ddddff","#ccccdd","#f3f3f3","#f0ffff")

    // Set the fonts, that create the snowflakes. Add as many fonts as you like
    var snowtype=new Array("Times","Arial","Times","Verdana")

    // Set the letter that creates your snowflake (recommended: * )
    var snowletter="*"

    // Set the speed of sinking (recommended values range from 0.3 to 2)
    var sinkspeed=0.6

    // Set the maximum-size of your snowflakes
    var snowmaxsize=30

    // Set the minimal-size of your snowflakes
    var snowminsize=8

    // Set the snowing-zone
    // Set 1 for all-over-snowing, set 2 for left-side-snowing
    // Set 3 for center-snowing, set 4 for right-side-snowing
    var snowingzone=1

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // CONFIGURATION ENDS HERE
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // Do not edit below this line
    var snow=new Array()
    var marginbottom
    var marginright
    var timer
    var i_snow=0
    var x_mv=new Array();
    var crds=new Array();
    var lftrght=new Array();
    var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent
    var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/)
    var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
    var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/)
    var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera

    function randommaker(range) {
            rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random())
        return rand
    }

    function initsnow() {
            if (ie5 || opera) {
                    marginbottom = document.body.scrollHeight
                    marginright = document.body.clientWidth-15
            }
            else if (ns6) {
                    marginbottom = document.body.scrollHeight
                    marginright = window.innerWidth-15
            }
            var snowsizerange=snowmaxsize-snowminsize
            for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
                    crds[i] = 0;
                lftrght[i] = Math.random()*15;
                x_mv[i] = 0.03 + Math.random()/10;
                    snow[i]=document.getElementById("s"+i)
                    snow[i].style.fontFamily=snowtype[randommaker(snowtype.length)]
                    snow[i].size=randommaker(snowsizerange)+snowminsize
                    snow[i].style.fontSize=snow[i].size+'px';
                    snow[i].style.color=snowcolor[randommaker(snowcolor.length)]
                    snow[i].style.zIndex=1000
                    snow[i].sink=sinkspeed*snow[i].size/5
                    if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
                    if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
                    if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
                    if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
                    snow[i].posy=randommaker(2*marginbottom-marginbottom-2*snow[i].size)
                    snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+'px';
                    snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+'px';
            }
            movesnow()
    }

    function movesnow() {
            for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
                    crds[i] += x_mv[i];
                    snow[i].posy+=snow[i].sink
                    snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i])+'px';
                    snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+'px';

                    if (snow[i].posy>=marginbottom-2*snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])){
                            if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
                            if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
                            if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
                            if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
                            snow[i].posy=0
                    }
            }
            var timer=setTimeout("movesnow()",50)
    }

    for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
            document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"'>"+snowletter+"</span>")
    }
    if (browserok) {
            window.onload=initsnow
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: That code is very old and poorly written.

Comment: It would help if you posted a demo where the code is visible, like on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @epascarello You have a problem with IE5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
snow[i].style.zIndex=1000
```

set it to

```
snow[i].style.zIndex=-1;
```

Comment: Uhh, didn't you read `// Do not edit below this line`